# messages to break hash modulus 2^n

Tags: hash

Let $H_{2^n}(k,m)$ be a hash function where $k$ and $n$ are unknown and $m$ is a message in the format $(m[0], m[1], ..., m[s])$, with $m[i] < 2^n$ for all $0 < i \le s$. Define the hash as:

$H_{2^n}(k,m) = (k^s + m[1]k^{s -1}+\dots + m[s -1]k + m[s]) \;mod\;2^n$

The attacker sends a set $M = \{m_1, m_2, ..., m_a\}$ of messages and wins the game if $H_{2^n}(k,m_i) = H_{2^n}(k,m_j)$ for some $m_i,m_j \in M$ where $m_i \ne m_j$.

How can the attacker choose a set $M$ that will surely win the game?

---

I'm guessing there must be some trick with the last part of the message (i.e. $m[s]$), for example, if the attacker sends a set $M$ where $m_i = (0,0,\dots, 1 + 2^i)$, it's possible to ignore $k^s$ and if $M$ is big enough, than its elements will collide for sure, but I don't think this is the right way to use the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If k is even

1. Choose a string m
2. Choose any block of m other than the last
3. Flip the most signficant bit of that block.

They collide because you effictively shift all bits of that block one place to the left. If $x \equiv y \mod 2^{n-1}$ then $2x \equiv 2y \mod 2^n$.

Additionally if $k$ is even all strings with their last $n$ blocks equal collide. This is because the previous blocks have a coefficient congruent to 0 mod $2^n$. (They're multiplied by a multiple of $2^n$.)

Comment: I didn't understand the step 3. $m$ can be an object in the form $(5, 20, 432, 4, 7, ..., 43)$ where no value of it is greater than $2^n$ for some $n$, $m$ isn't made of binaries, just integers

Comment: @Daniel: Any integer can be represented in binary. Values mod $2^n$ can fit in an unsigned $n$-bit number.  Consider $k = 2, n = 2, m_1 = (2,1), m_2(=0,1)$. $H(m_1) = 2 * 2 + 1 \space mod \space 4 = 0 + 1 \space mod \space 4 = 1$. $H(m_2) = 2 * 0 + 1 \space mod \space 4 = 0 + 1 \space mod \space 4 = 1$.

Comment: To clarify. When I say most significant bit (binary digit) I meant the left most bit in an n-bit number. ie. the one having value $2^{n-1}$ if set. Not most significant meaning the leftmost 1 bit.